# Bash - Iterate over map from k8s secrets call

Tags: bash, kubernetes, iteration, kubernetes-secrets

I am requesting the details of a k8s secret:

```
kubectl get secret mySecret -o jsonpath='{.data}'
```

The answer of the call gives me the following map:

```
'map[first_password:ZXhhbXBsZQ0K second_password:ZXhhbXBsZQ0K third_password:ZXhhbXBsZQ0K]'
```

I want to iterate now with BASH through this map, to write the values in a string, that looks like this:

```
first_password ZXhhbXBsZQ0K

second_password ZXhhbXBsZQ0K

third_password ZXhhbXBsZQ0K
```

Does anyone know how to this with BASH?

For now I have this:

```
items=$(echo "$(kubectl get secret mySecret -o jsonpath='{.data}')" | jq -c -r '.[]')
for item in ${items[@]}; do
    echo $item
done
```

This just prints three times the password ZXhhbXBsZQ0K.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `-o jsonpath` for this. You can get `kubectl` to output direct to json which `jq` can then parse entirely. So something like `kubectl get secret mySecret -o json | jq ....`

Comment: @BlenderFox Thanks for the quick answer. When I use the cmd: kubectl get secret mySecret -o json, I get a quite huge Json file with lot of attributes, but I only need the "data" attribute where the acutal secrets are stored. I have the feeling it might be easier to work with the map I am currently getting, because it immediately has the values that I am looking for.

Comment: You should make `items` an array. You define the variable as scalar string, but then iterate over it as if it were an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`kubectl get secret mySecret -o json | jq -r '.data | keys[] as $key | "\($key):\(.[$key])"'`

Running this against my grafana secret in my cluster with the following structure:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "admin-password": "{hidden}",
        "admin-user": "{redacted}",
        "ldap-toml": ""
    },
    "kind": "Secret",
    ...
}
```

Gives me this:

```
admin-password:{hidden}
admin-user:{redacted}
ldap-toml:
```